# how to fetch data in firebase by user id

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have users inserted into firebase database , every user with his own data (email, name , age ....), I try to get data of a single user - the connected device's user - my function is bringing data but its bringing the entire database , all users , could you please help to solve the issue ,
here is my code :

```
componentWillMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        firebase.database().ref('friends')
            .on('value', (snapshot) => {
                const data = snapshot.val() || [];
                this.handleData(data);
            });
      }
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not already, you need to split the information regarding each user into subcollections.

For example: friends > user_1 > email, name, age......

Then in your Firebase query you need to specify the subcollection. Right now you have it returning every entry under 'friends'. It should look something like this:

```
componentWillMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        firebase.database().ref('friends/' + user.uid) //reference uid of logged in user like so
            .on('value', (snapshot) => {
                const data = snapshot.val() || [];
                this.handleData(data);
            });
      }
   });
  }
```